# How to install Windows 7 to non-C: volume letter?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

It is possible to have Windows 7/8.1/10 reside on a volume with driver letter other than C: ? I hope to have this so that I can test whether my softwares/installers can run correctly when the system stock directories are not standard, for example, `F:\Windows` , `F:\Program Files`, `F:\Program Files (x86)`, `F:\ProgramData` .

When installing from ISO, I Shift+F10 call out diskpart.exe, create partitions and assign letter `F:` to the 12GB partition then install Win7 on it. BUT, when installation is done, that 12GB partition still gets drive letter **C:**, sigh.

[image]

[image]

Trying to change drive letter from diskmgmt.msc is vain, Windows says **The parameter is incorrect.**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to create a partition with the drive letter C and not install to it? In your example e.g. you could assign volume 2 the drive letter C.

Comment: Tried it. Same result.

Comment: You cannot change the partition letter the OS boots from.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible with any unaltered installation kit. The letter C: is reserved for the drive or partition that the windows operating system is installed on. If you multi boot, then the windows that you start in will always show as the C: drive by default. Windows practically always assigns C: to itself when booting, no matter your partition configuration is.
For example, if you have 2 partitions with W7 and W10, if you boot from drive with W7, that one would be C: and other one D:. In the same computer, if you now boot from drive with W10 and it will become C: and drive with W7 will become drive D:.

Comment: Then where can I get the "altered installation kit"? from Microsoft?

Comment: You will have to make your own. Tools like NLite/Rt7Lite, WinPE, WinReducer (for W10) and many similar ones can help you do that.

Comment: @Overmind Can you provide a link to a page describing this feature of choosing a different letter? ZI tried searching and can't find anything.